# How do I find data sets using a particular Schema.org entity?

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, opendata

I am trying to decide whether to use schema.org entities in my own open source app, for potential compatibility with existing open data sets. So I'm looking for usage of relevant schema.org entities "in the wild".

Right now I'm looking for dietary supplement data, IE http://schema.org/DietarySupplement, or http://health-lifesci.schema.org/DietarySupplement

I've been searching for semantic web search engines, and have only found Swoogle, but I get no results for that URI, or "service temporarily unavailable".

The DietarySupplement page on schema.org says that "between 10 and 100" domains are using this entity. Is that talking about DNS, abstract domains that are defined on Schema.org, abstractions defined elsewhere, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There are only a couple of other resources I can find on this subject.

1. [Web Data Commons - RDFa, Microdata, and Microformat Data
   Sets](http://webdatacommons.org/structureddata/index.html)
2. [BuiltWith trends - Microdata Usage Statistics](http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/Microdata)